# Display Firestore data into UIPicker Swift 4

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am still new in swift development, my problem is, I have Firestore structure as below:

[image]

the problem is to display the list of title from firestore into a uipicker, I need to get data into an array like below:
[firsProgramme, secondProgramme, thirdProgramme]

I managed to display all the "title" from firestore in the string, not in the array

below is the code:

```
func getprogram() {
 let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("Programme").getDocuments()
        {
            (querySnapshot, err) in

            if let err = err
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)");
            }
            else
            {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let data = document.data()

                    let program = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                  //  let agencyId = document.documentID
                    print(program)
                    //print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())");
                }

            }
    }

}
```

result print(program) return as below :

firstprogramme

secondprogramme

thirdprogramme

the other part for UIPicker is already being managed well.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you class create an array variable to hold information about your programs:

`var programsArray: [String] = []`

When reading data from Firebase, instead of `print(program)` use `programsArray.append(program)`. Call UIPickerView reload function after you have all data.

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.your_picker_view.reloadAllComponents()
}`

And of course, use this array inside your pickerview datasource methods.